# Mock static method in Quarkus

Tags: junit, mockito, quarkus

Hi I'm new to Quarkus and I've one Quarkus app which has one filter, from filter I'm calling static method I want to mock that static method call. How can I do that?

```
@Provider
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{    
  
  @Context
  HttpServerRequest request;

  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    if (isPermittedPath()) {
        return;
    }
    String company = Util.getCompany(request.host());
    //some code here
  }
}
```

I want to mock call of `Util.getCompany(request.host())` method.

I'm following this document to write test cases https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing

Comment: Technically, Powermock can mock static methods. **BUT** please reconsider your implementation: it is much better IMO to use a CDI service than static methods to implement business logic or even configuration such as what I suspect is implemented in `Util.getCompany()`.

Comment: it's just utility method that subtracts subdomain from host url and returns that . is there any other way to mock it except wrapping it in CDI service?

Comment: I suspect that what you really want is a way to provide a mock value for the `company`. You probably cannot mock the `request` itself, because you are running integration tests on localhost. Powermock can extend Mockito with the ability to [mock static methods](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method). Still, I would consider a `CompanyResolver` CDI service that knows how to transform a "host" to a "company" and uses your `Util.getCompany` internally. Concerns are better separated this way, IMO, and testability is straightforward.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Does coding business logic in CDI beans is a good practice ? I think it's beter to see CDI beans as simple and thin orchestrator to POJO that hold business logic (mostly in static methods) ?

Comment: @bertranddeweer Well, people are using "beans" (meaning components managed by a DI framework, like Spring, CDI, even EJB) to code business logic. In many cases they are POJOs - their special annotations take effect if they run inside a container, but their structure does not preclude them from running standalone. I do not see a reason why this is a bad practice - any references? I would not object seeing the "beans" as orchestrators and the logic implemented elsewhere, it's probably a matter of preference. Static methods have nuances (mock/test, handle state, ...), I do not prefer them.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I think that framework like Spring tend the developper to code business logic in what they called 'service layer'.For most of the developper, this in indeed more natural. Because they have an entity / JPA layer. Im agree, an object who lives in an hibernate session shouldn't hold business logic. But does a DogService knows how to make a dog eating? Or does a Dog knows how to eat ? By coding all the business logic in service layer you can quickly have very BIG service and difficult to maintain. Here is a reference :https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html